# How to iterate through an Object attributes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, loops, angular, iteration, ngfor

Here's my object (It has n number of dynamic keys. I've only shown two in the example below)

```
let obj = {
abc:["some text", "some more text"],
xyz:["more text", "what do you think?", "I'm tired now"]

}
```

Here's my attempt to loop throw the above and print all the values

```
 <div *ngFor='let item of obj ; let i = index;'>
            <p *ngFor="let value of obj.i">{{value}}
 </div>
```

But the above doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong and what's the correct syntax?

Comment: Did you try `obj[i]` instead of `obj.i`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let o of obj">
   <p *ngFor="let objArrayElement of generateArray(o)"> {{objArrayElement}} </p>
</li>
```

where `generateArray` looks like:

```
generateArray(obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
}
```

Comment: @Aarmora nice to know that it was helpful for you. :)

Comment: but let o of obj in angular2 is not allowed, because obj is not iterateble, correct?

Answer (score 26):

slight modification to @eg16's answer and it worked like a charm for me -

the generateArray function looks like this-

```
generateArray(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return {key:key, value:obj[key]}});
}
```

and the template -

```
<li *ngFor="let item of generateArray(data)">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
```

Answer (score 21):

Starting with version 6.1, a [KeyValue Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) is made available by Angular:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of (data | keyvalue)">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
```

This makes previous workarounds using Object.keys references or own implementations thereof obsolete.