# Nested arrays in Firebase Database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to work with `angulafire2` to use my data stored in Firebase Database in my Angular app and I'm having some trouble with nested arrays.

I have an structure that looks like this:

```
items{
    item1{
        name: item1,
        subitems{
            subitem1{
                name: subitem1
            },
            subitem2{
                name: subitem2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a `FirebaseListObservable` to get the `items` array.

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
[...]
this.items = this.af.database.list('/items');
```

And the problem appears when I try to display the data.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <span>{{(item)?.name}}</span>

    <div *ngFor="let subitem of (item)?.subitems">
        <span>{{(subitem)?.name}}</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

I get an error because `item.subitems` is not recognized as an array.

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

---

**EDIT:** I made a plunker that uses a test database in Firebase as the example above. [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/zxwLiw8y6rlm6kQVbRGC)

Comment: items is object not array, you cannot iterate over it

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Yep, I understand that, but Firebase stores the data like this. How I'm supposed to iterate over it?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No sorry, my solution was to restructure all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, not with firebase but that doesn't matter in this case.

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
[...]
this.items = this.af.database.list('/items');
this.items.forEach(record => {
  console.Debug(record); // show output
  record.subitems.forEach(subRecord => { 
    console.Debug(subRecord); // show output too
  });
});
```

When excuting this, you get console logs right?
In my case I do and I got same construction in view.
I'm watching this issue in case it get solved.

Comment: Already tried that and should use `suscribe()` method because those are asynchronous arrays. But still don't understand how to display the data without using complicated structures.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in my case.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.prop}}
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let subitem of item.subItems">
        <td>{{subitem.prop}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Try it like this first, this is working after changing some property names.
After that, replace the elements for your own elements and test it after every change to see if it's still working.

Comment: It's the same I tried, doesn't work. Also, I'm using asynchronous arrays.

Comment: Can you make A plunker so I can try Some things?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase structures should generally avoid being deeply nested. The deeper your structure is the more complicated they are.

But you can map over the structure and convert an object to an array using something like `Object.keys(obj)` or the experimental `Object.value(obj)` or write you own function as further on below

For example to convert the keys for a level

```
this.items = db.list('/items').map(items => {
  return items.map(item => {
    return {
       item: Object.keys(item.subitem)
    }
  });
});
```

You can also do something like this using a function in the ngFor loop [found in this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059552/how-to-iterate-through-an-object-attributes-in-angular-2)

```
<li *ngFor="let o of obj">
   <p *ngFor="let item of generateArray(o)">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}  </p>
</li>
```

using this function

```
generateArray(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return {key:key, value:obj[key]}});
}
```

Which should give you the keys and the values